# Java Start and Stop Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I cannot figure out how to stop a `Thread` in `Java`.

I have a `function` that creates the `Thread` and starts it. Now when I start the program, I want it to start the `Thread`. After that if the `button` is pressed then I want the `Thread` to stop and when the `button` is pressed again, I want the `Thread` to start over, or resume (it does not matter).

My `function` that creates the `Thread`:

```
private void startRecordingUserInput() {
    AudioDispatcher dispatcher =
            AudioDispatcherFactory.fromDefaultMicrophone(44100, 2048, 0);


    PitchDetectionHandler pdh = new PitchDetectionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handlePitch(PitchDetectionResult res, AudioEvent e) {
            final float pitchInHz = res.getPitch();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    pitchText.setText("" + pitchInHz);
                    gameView.setSingerArrowPitch(pitchInHz);
                    gameView.setCurrentTime(mid);
                    gameView.invalidate();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    AudioProcessor pitchProcessor = new PitchProcessor(PitchProcessor.PitchEstimationAlgorithm.FFT_YIN, 44100, 2048, pdh);
    dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(pitchProcessor);

    Thread audioThread = new Thread(dispatcher, "Audio Thread");
    audioThread.start();
}
```

And the part where I start it and want to `start/stop` the `Thread`.

```
    //Start the Thread
    startRecordingUserInput();

    playRecordButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(!isPlaying){

                //Start the Thread again if it is not running or 
                //make a new one

                isPlaying = true;

            } else if(isPlaying){

                //Stop the Thread

                isPlaying = false;

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Turing85 My question is, how can I Start and Stop the Thread when it is needed

Comment: I would basically follow this example (ignore the German in it): http://javawiki.sowas.com/doku.php?id=java:thread-pausieren . One basically extends a Thread and adds a flag, that one could set from outside the thread - e.g. in your listener in the GUI-thread. If the flag has been changed, the next time the if-statement is synchronously checked **inside** the run()-method, it will put any further processing on hold. There are also Thread-runners (such as `SwingWorker`, `Runnable` or the likes), that might ease your burden.

Comment: You have mutlipe layers of wrapping. You define your runnable, but this seems to do some GUI-related stuff, no actual processing. The `AudioDispatcher` seems to be the part doing all the work. All methods in `Thread` that could be used to implement what you want are marked deprecated. If you were to use e.g. `suspend()` and `resume()`, you would have to rely on `AudioDispatcher` to have those methods properly implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might use `TarsosDSP` in the future and faces the same problem then the easiest way is to make a global `dispatcher`

```
dispatcher = AudioDispatcherFactory.fromDefaultMicrophone(22050,1024,0);
```

And simply `stop` the `Thread` with this:

```
dispatcher.stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

a thread runs until its run method completed, so if you want to keep on running it then add an infinite loop in the run method then inside run method add a condition for "isPlaying==false" then break the loop.
again when you want to start the thread on button click then make "isPlaying=true" and call thread.start() method.

```
public void run() {
   while(true) {
      if(!isPlaying) {
         break;
      }
      // Do other stuff here.
   }
}
```

Comment: Correct. Stop method in java has been deprecated for a long time now. Thus I'm afraid the only conclusive way of stopping a thread is to let it finish. However, if your thread is expected to enter in sleep or wait you can call Thread.interrupt() which will throw an exception and when properly handled, it'll be able to pull you out.

Comment: yes instead of using an extra flag "isPlaying" you can use the method "isInterrupted()" in run method and if it is true then break the loop.basically when we call thread.interrupt() it just makes a flag true for the interruption and same flag is returned by isInterrupted() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways

You can get all running threads with

```
Thread.getAllStackTraces()
```

You can "un-safely" stop a thread by doing

```
Thread t;
t.stop(); 
//or
t.destroy();
//or 
t.suspend();
//Or to resume
t.resume();
```

Or, you can go the safe route, and learn synchronization, and use

```
Thread t;
t.wait();
t.notify();
```

Also, this to will not always work, but you can do

```
 boolean pause() { isPaused = !isPaused; }

 @Override
 public void run() {
      while (running) { if (!isPaused) doThread(); }
 }
```

Comment: As much as I have read then using `destroy` and `stop` should be bad practice.

Comment: I would surround the check on pause with `synchronized(this) {...}` in order to not have the value changed while it's still being evaluated, hence creating a lock while performing the check.

Comment: I denoted the bad practiced methods as: "You can "un-safely" stop a thread by doing"